# Comparing percentages with unequal sample size

Tags: proportion, descriptive-statistics, percentage

I am comparing the percentage of 5 areas with regards to the magnitude of poverty, income distribution, proportion of women etc. Two of the five areas are independent cities and the three other are provinces(one province has two cities, the other has one city and the other is a rural province with no city) and all are part of one administrative region.

Usually I compute the percentage of one sector [(example:(woman-headed household) /(total household of a place)] and compare the percentage across the five areas without using an inferential statistics. The comparison is based solely on the percentages.The two independent cities always yielded different percentages(either lower or higher) compared to the three provinces.

The inherent difference characteristics between urban and rural areas probably played the part.But  the size of  each two cities is only half of each three provinces. **Given that the gathering of data is scientific and unbiased, does the different sizes of population/sample affect the comparison?**

Comment: The estimates of the percentages will have different precision from samples of different sizes but if you decide on a statistical technique it should take care of that.